# Xpath - select nodes depending on preceding-siblings and following-siblings

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <p><c type="changeStart"/>​<style type="underline">text</style><c type="changeEnd"/><t/>In addition 
        to voting Finance Company and Business Company, Inc.: (i) the name 
        of the <c type="changeStart"/>new public entity<c type="changeEnd"/> will be “Finance Company.” 
        as Finance Company’s corporate existence is perpetual as opposed to Business Company, Inc.’s corprate 
        existence terminating <c type="changeStart"/>   <c type="changeEnd"/>
    </p>
</doc>
```

I need to select the nodes exist between `<c type="changeStart"/>` and `<c type="changeEnd"/>`. So in above xml following nodes should be selected,

- ​`<style type="underline">text</style>`
- `new public entity`
- two white spaces ('  ')

I've written following xpath for that,

```
//*[preceding-sibling::c[@type = 'changeStart'] and following-sibling::c[@type = 'changeEnd']][not(c [@type="changeStart"])]
```

But it does not select the correct nodes. any suggesion how can I modify my xpath to select what I need?

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible XPath :

```
//node()[
    preceding-sibling::*[1][self::c/@type='changeStart']
        and
    following-sibling::*[1][self::c/@type='changeEnd']
]
```

The above XPath select nodes that :

- *directly preceded* by `<c type="changeStart"/>`, and..
- *directly followed* by `<c type="changeEnd"/>`

Comment: This will only work if there is exactly one node between the change markers, correct?

Comment: I see. And there is no way to make it work with multiple nodes in between, is there?

Comment: There is no way using XPath 1.0, as far as I can see. There *might be* a way using XSLT 2.0 though...

Comment: @Markus, Yes, there *is* such an XPath 1.0 expression -- see it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression** (similar to the approach of @Flynn1179, but uses strict `>` comparison, and also has restrictions to exclude nodes, whose parents are also in the changed nodes, and to exclude from the result the `<c>` elements themselves. Also, I am using the `preceding::` axis and not the `preceding-sibling::` axis. This allows for the `<c>` start and end type elements to be on different levels in the document (not siblings)):

```
 //node()
          [count(preceding::c[@type='changeStart']) 
           > count(preceding::c[@type='changeEnd'])
           and not(parent::*
                 [count(preceding::c[@type='changeStart']) 
                 > count(preceding::c[@type='changeEnd'])]
                 )
           and not(self::c[@type[.='changeStart' or .='changeEnd']])
          ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select=
    "//node()
              [count(preceding::c[@type='changeStart']) 
               > count(preceding::c[@type='changeEnd'])
               and not(parent::*
                     [count(preceding::c[@type='changeStart']) 
                     > count(preceding::c[@type='changeEnd'])]
                     )
               and not(self::c[@type[.='changeStart' or .='changeEnd']])
              ]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',position(), '. ')"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:

```
<doc>
    <p><c type="changeStart"/><style type="underline">text</style><c type="changeEnd"/><t/>In addition 
        to voting Finance Company and Business Company, Inc.: (i) the name 
        of the <c type="changeStart"/>new public entity<c type="changeEnd"/> will be “Finance Company.” 
        as Finance Company’s corporate existence is perpetual as opposed to Business Company, Inc.’s corprate 
        existence terminating <c type="changeStart"/>   <c type="changeEnd"/>
    </p>
</doc>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
1. <style type="underline">text</style>
2. new public entity
```

In order to also get the text node with the two spaces, delete the      `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` declaration from the above transformation.

**Here is a much more challenging case**. Applying the transformation on this XML document:

```
<t>
  <x>
   <c type="changeStart"/>
    <y> content
      <z>
        <p>

        </p>
      </z>
    </y>
   <c type="changeStart"/>
    <v>

    </v>
   <c type="changeEnd"/>
   <r/>
   <c type="changeEnd"/>
   <s/>
  </x>
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
1. <y> content
      <z>
      <p/>
   </z>
</y>
2. <v/>
3. <r/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
//node()[
    count(preceding-sibling::c[@type='changeStart']) !=
    count((. | preceding-sibling::c)[@type='changeEnd'])
  ]
```

However, this is very dependent on your 'changeStart' and 'changeEnd' markers being done correctly, with opening and closing pairs. If you can guarantee this will be the case, this should get close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Good, +1. Needs to be modified a little bit -- to use the `preceding::` axis instead of `preceding-sibling` and to select exactly the nodes the OP wants: no `<c>` elements and no nodes that are children of selected elements.

Comment: I guess you didn't try it- it does select exactly what the OP needs. To be honest though, given the title says 'select nodes depending on preceding-*siblings* and following-*siblings*', I'll stick with those.

Comment: Flynn1179, I tried the XPath expression from this answer. In *This* case it selects the wanted nodes. In other cases, though, it selects unwanted nodes -- such as `<c>` nodes.